# How to annotate function argument that takes instances of classes that have __dict__ attribute and not __slots__, and vice-versa

Tags: python, annotations, type-hinting, slots

Let's say I have a function `dict_to_string`:

```
>>> def dict_to_string(d: ??) -> str:
...     return ';'.join(f"{k},{v}" for k, v in vars(d).items())
```

What type hint is required to ensure that `d` has `__dict__` and not `__slots__`, (or vice-versa, for future reference).

I know I can just check `hasattr(d, '__dict__')` and not `__slots__`, but I would like to know if it is possible to type hint.

Comment: Do you mean you want to ensure that a class *does not* have a `__slots__` attribute, along with checking that it *does* have a `__dict__`? I believe it's possible to do the latter, but I don't think the former is possible.

Comment: Yes, I *want to ensure that a class does not have a __slots__ attribute, along with checking that it does have a __dict__*

Comment: I don't think you can check if a class *doesn't* have an attribute. You could likely do the `__dict__` check using `Protocol` from `typing` though. I think `Protocol` works on attributes as well as methods.

Comment: I see, could you post an answer? Not very well versed with `Protocol`.

Comment: So, I just spent 10 minutes writing an answer, and it doesn't work for `__dict__`. I can get it to check other attributes properly, but it fails for `__dict__` specifically. I might write a separate Q&A though to address the generalized question here, since I don't think that that's documented anywhere.

Comment: Ah! Nevermind. Hopefully will be able to figure out something eventually. Thanks for trying!

Comment: See my self Q&A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64185810/how-can-i-use-static-checking-to-ensure-an-object-has-a-certain-method-attribute/64185811#64185811). You may be able to get something working if you play around with it.