# How can I use static checking to ensure an object has a certain method/attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing, duck-typing

Is there I way that I can annotate a function to ensure that an object being passed into the function has a certain method or attribute, but where I don't care about its actual type?

Pycharm internally uses a syntax that looks like `{b}` to indicate what methods/attributes it's inferred are required for the object, but that doesn't appear to be valid Python syntax:

```
def func(a: {b}):  # Error
    a.b = 1
```

Is there a way to get the type checker to assist in duck typing, where I only care what methods/attributes the object has, not what the type of the objects are, and where I can't modify the types I want to check for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python type hint for classes that support \_\_getitem\_\_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127855/python-type-hint-for-classes-that-support-getitem) Both, the question and the accepted answer should be updated there, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`Protocol`s](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/) can be used. I'm documenting it here because I found this to be a difficult topic to search for; especially checking for the existence of attributes.

For ensuring the presence of an attribute:

```
from typing import Protocol

class HasFoo(Protocol):     # Define what's required
    foo: int

class Foo:                  # This class fulfills the protocol implicitly
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 1

class Bar:
    def __init__(self):     # This class fails to implicitly fulfill the protocol
        self.bar = 2

def foo_func(f: HasFoo):
    pass

foo_func(Foo())             # Type check succeeds
foo_func(Bar())             # Type check fails
```

Note the type hint after `foo`. It's required for that line to be syntactically valid, and the type must match the inferred type of the checked attributes. `typing.Any` can be used as a placeholder if you care about the existence of `foo`, but not its type.

---

Similarly, the same can be done for checking methods:

```
class HasFoo(Protocol):
    def foo(self):
        pass

class Foo:
    def foo(self):
        pass
    
class Bar:
    def bar(self):
        pass

def func(f: HasFoo):
    pass

func(Foo())             # Succeeds
func(Bar())             # Fails
```

---

Type checking was done via `Pycharm 2020.2.2`.