# Python typing, mypy infer return type based on class method return type

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Consider the case when I have different classes implementing the same method while returning different types.

```py
class A:
    def method(self) -> float:
        return 3.14

class B:
    def method(self) -> str:
        return 'a string'

def do_method(x):
    return x.method()

r = do_method(A())
reveal_type(r)  # Revealed type is 'Any'
```

Mypy is not being able to infer the exact return type of function `do_method()` which depends on its argument `x`. How can I help Mypy achieve this?

Note: Please also consider that number of such classes that I want to use with the function `do_method()` is too many, so one doesn't want to change them all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use static checking to ensure an object has a certain method/attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64185810/how-can-i-use-static-checking-to-ensure-an-object-has-a-certain-method-attribute)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [generic protocol](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html?highlight=covariant#generic-protocols) to do what you need. But it should be minded that mypy requires the covariance of the return type of the function of protocol when it is a `TypeVar`, so we must explicitly state this by `covariant=True`, otherwise the variable is considered as an invariant by default.

A covariant return type of a method is one that can be replaced by a "narrower" type when the method is overridden in a subclass.

```
from typing import TypeVar, Protocol

T = TypeVar('T', covariant=True)

class Proto(Protocol[T]):
    def method(self) -> T: ...
    
class A:
    def method(self) -> float:
        return 3.14
        
class B:
    def method(self) -> str:
        return 'a string'
        
def do_method(x: Proto[T]) -> T:
    return x.method()
    
r1 = do_method(A())
reveal_type(r1)  # Revealed type is 'builtins.float*'
r2 = do_method(B())
reveal_type(r2)  # Revealed type is 'builtins.str*'
```