# Is there a Python type for annotation that represents something that has `__contains__` method?

Tags: python, types, annotations, typing

I look for `Type` such that the below type-checks OK:

```
import typing

def f(a: str, collection: Type):
    return a in collection
```

that is, `Type` asserts that `collection` has `__contains__`.

Comment: [collections.abc.Container](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Container).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I keep [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) page bookmarked, because it's a pain to search for, but is also very helpful.

As you can see at the top of that table, a `Container` is an object that has a `__contains__` method:

```
from typing import Container

def f(a: str, collection: Container[str]):
    return a in collection
```

The table references classes in `collections`, but `typing` contains generic, typed variants of the same classes.

If `collections.Container`/`typing.Container` didn't exist, you could also [create your own `Protocol`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64185810/3000206) to have it hinted properly.

Comment: Note that [typing.Container is deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Container) since version 3.9: `collections.abc.Container` now supports subscripting (`[]`). See [**PEP 585**](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/).